# Installed the Zimbra on server

Tags: ubuntu, email, zimbra

Following the tutorials of the how to install the Zimbra Mail Server. I don't I can the access the browser to continue the installation. What do I do ?
The Hosts I configured to mail.mydomain.com.
Don't I can access the https://mail.mydomain.com:7071/

Answer (score 1):

Try accessing it by IP address, like:

> https://192.168.0.1:7071/

Obviously substitue your own IP as appropriate.  In order to reach it by hostname you would need a DNS entry somewhere for mail.mydomain.com, but there's not nearly enough info in your question to gather what kind of setup this is.  In any case, you should be able to connect to the web admin page with the IP as above if Zimbra installed correctly.  You'll probably have to click through some browser warnings about an untrusted/self-signed certificate and/or mismatched hostname (as the cert will likely be for mail.mydomain.com but you'll be connecting by IP).